How to do recursive type coercion in Lean
I have a type
inductive Pair where
| zero
| pair (a b: Pair)

and I would like to use () for Pair.zero and (a, b) for Pair.pair a b, recursively.
After finding a similar question, I have tried creating recursive Coe instances like this:
instance Pair.coeZero: Coe Unit Pair where
  coe := fun _ => Pair.zero

instance Pair.coePair
  [Coe A Pair]
  [Coe B Pair]
:
  Coe (A × B) Pair
where
  coe := fun ⟨a, b⟩ => Pair.pair a b

which does seem to work okay
-- These work:
def p0: Pair := ()
def p1: Pair := ((), ())

-- TBD with more instances?
def p2: Pair := (Pair.zero, Pair.zero) -- `Coe (Pair × Pair) Pair`
def p3: Pair := (Pair.zero, ())        -- `Coe (Pair × B) Pair`
def p4: Pair := ((), Pair.zero)        -- `Coe (A × Pair) Pair`

However, it creates issues with coercing Subtype (_: Pair → Prop) to Pair, which works
when these instances are not defined. Take the function
def foo (p: { p: Pair // p = Pair.zero }): p = Pair.zero :=
  p.property

This function produces no errors when I comment out the definition of coePair. However, when coePair is defined, I get
(deterministic) timeout at `typeclass`, maximum number of heartbeats (20000) has been reached
Use `set_option synthInstance.maxHeartbeats <num>` to set the limit.
Additional diagnostic information may be available using the `set_option diagnostics true` command.

What am I doing wrong?

TL;DR: Use CoeOut instead of Coe.
Looking at the chapter Type Classes of the official tutorial and then the source code, I noticed that besides Coe, there is also CoeSort, CoeOut and a few others. I must admit I do not understand the difference between some of them, despite staring at the docs for quite some time (What do you mean, "left-to-right coercion"?).
Out of all of them, CoeOut appears to be the one I ought to use, and indeed it works. Coercing A × Pair, B × Pair and Pair × Pair can be handled with one instance for each, or one may define a single instance of
CoeOut Pair Pair (I have not experienced any issues with it despite it looking like it could trigger some infinite coercing).
So, the solution appears to be:
instance Pair.coeZero: CoeOut Unit Pair where
  coe := fun _ => Pair.zero

instance Pair.coeId: CoeOut Pair Pair where
  coe := id

instance Pair.coePair
  [CoeOut A Pair]
  [CoeOut B Pair]
:
  CoeOut (A × B) Pair
where
  coe := fun ⟨a, b⟩ => Pair.pair a b

I, however, cannot vouch for that this is the "right way" to do it.

I've discovered this does not compose with other Coe instances, eg. Coe Nat Pair that would handle a standard way to encode naturals as pairs. To fix that, one can define instance Pair.coeOutCoe [Coe A Pair]: CoeOut A Pair where coe := fun p => p. It does look like hack to me -- I feel like I should not be writing this kind of code. On the other hand, it works (AFAICT).
